# Get count on filtered subqueries in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

If I have a parent model and a child model, how can I then list *all* child objects of a parent object, and have a *filtered* count for each child object, when listing them?

To give an example, assume we have these models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ....

class Tag(models.Model):
    ....

class Article(models.Model)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

Then we have a DetailView for a Category, in which all SubCatoegories for that Category are listed. In this list, we want to have a count on each SubCategory entry, on the number of articles it contains that *also* is of a certain tag (that is, not a count on *all* articles of that SubCategory, which seems much more trivial to build). Something like this:

```
{% for sub_category in category.sub_category_set.all %}
    {{ sub_category.name }} -- {{ sub_category.articles_set.filter(tag='xyz').all|length }}
```

I guess this has to be done in the views.py and/or models.py in some way in the end. I just wrote it like this to clarify what I mean. So, how can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Two questions: 1. has sub_category FK to article?  2. What is wrong with sub_category.articles_set.filter(tag='xyz').count()?

Comment: 1. No, only article to sub_category.
2. I don't think you can do filtering in the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you'll have to do this in the view. You can use annotation to get the number of filtered articles for each subcategory:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def my_view(request, other, arguments):
    ...
    subcategories = category.sub_category_set.filter(tag__tagname='xyz') \ 
                            .annotate(num_articles=Count('article__id'))
    ...
```

Pass `subcategories` to your template context, and in your template you can do this:

```
{% for subcategory in subcategories %}
    {{ subcategory.name }} -- {{ subcategory.num_articles }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How can I have this to work even if there are 0 articles with tag='xyz'?

Comment: You seem to have good knowledge of this, so maybe you could take a look at my new question, which extends this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636343/get-count-on-several-filtered-subqueries-in-template